# How to start Application when usb is connected?

Tags: android

How to start Application when usb is connected and application is not running?
I don't want add intent filter to activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.TestActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

Because when I do like this, if the application is running the TestActivity will go to the front and other activity will be inVisible.

Comment: why don't you put the intent filters in other activities too?

Comment: @user3290180 how can i decide which is in the front?

Answer (score 3):

The code you write start the `TestActivity` when usb is connected. So it is normal that the activity comes to foreground.

Maybe you should just register a `BroadcastReceiver` for that `Intent` :

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.YourReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</receiver>
```

By doing so your receiver will be call when usb is connected, and you can from there notify the user or start a service or whatever you like to do.

Comment: Sorry my comment is so late, I did this,but unfortunely there is a bug.The hardware from factory can't work normally when I put the intent filter to the recevierr, but it works normally when the filter is in the activity.So if i can't use the broadcast any ways more?

Comment: Can you post in your question the code of your receiver and the stack trace of the error ?